why can't i recover financial data for FTT-USD?
Why does the code respond by dropping the second part of the symbol string?
> getSymbols('FTT-USD')
[1] "FTT-USD"
> str(FTT-USD)
Error: object 'FTT' not found


Also, str(FTT-USD) is trying to do the calculation FTT - USD (subtraction), so R complains it can't find FTT immediately.

Use backticks to escape names with symbols: str(\FTT-USD`)`

You can use get here.
library(quantmod)

rm(list=ls())

getSymbols('FTT-USD')
ls()
# [1] "FTT-USD"

FTT.USD <- get("FTT-USD")
str(FTT.USD)


An xts object on 2019-07-31 / 2024-07-18 containing: 
  Data:    double [1815, 6]
  Columns: FTT-USD.Open, FTT-USD.High, FTT-USD.Low, FTT-USD.Close, FTT-USD.Volume ... with 1 more column
  Index:   Date [1815] (TZ: "UTC")
  xts Attributes:
    $ src    : chr "yahoo"
    $ updated: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2024-07-18 10:19:30"

plot(FTT.USD)



https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:FFT-USD_close_price_2021-2023.png
